# The structure of $\Bbb Z_n=\{ kmod(p)|(n,p)=1\}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

this question may seem stupid, but  the way a question was phrased by my lecturer has made me a tad confused.

So just to check my understanding first;

$\Bbb Z_p=\{0,1,2,3,....,p-1\}$  is the cyclic group of integers modulo p. the fact that it is prime just means that the only subgroups are the trivial subgroup and the group itself.

if it were not prime it would still have the same structure eg. 
$\Bbb Z_6=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.

now my question;

1) How do you find the group of units for some arbitrary group

2) What is the structure of $\Bbb Z_n=\{ kmod(p)|(n,p)=1\}$ ? I feel that it will not simply be {0,1,2,3,...n-1}

Comment: What do you denote *kmod*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $u\in \mathbb Z_n$ is a unit. Then there exists $x\in\mathbb Z_n$ such that $ux=1$ in $\mathbb Z_n$, or
$$ux\equiv 1\bmod n$$
in $\mathbb Z$. That is, there exists $y\in\mathbb Z$ such that $ux+ny=1$. By [Bézout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), this occurs if and only if $\gcd(u,n)=1$. Thus, the unit group of $\mathbb Z_n$ is the set of nonnegative integers less than and coprime to $n$:
$$U_n=\{u\in\mathbb Z: \gcd(u,n)=1\}$$

The structure of $U_n$ is very different from that of $\mathbb Z_n$. The most important difference is that it *is not closed under addition* and has no well-defined addition operation.

Comment: Thank you I get part 1) now , let me try to explain part 2) a little better $\Bbb Z_p=\{a mod(p)\}= \{0,1,2,3,...p-1\}$ right ? but then $\Bbb Z_n=\{k modp| (n,p)=1\}$ is defined a little differently , specifically the subscripts of $\Bbb Z$ are different but then both are given by a mod p . but the second one is reliant on n aswell this confuses me

Comment: @exodius: your notation is off; I have never seen that definition. Perhaps you mean $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$? Note that what you write also does not make much sense, since the elements are called $k$ but the condition is on $n$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin this is copied from a question given by my lecturer , perhaps it was a misprint ? here's an exact copy Show that if a ∈ Z, n ∈ N, (a, n) = 1 then $a
^φ(n)$ ≡ 1Mod(n). Hint:
Consider Un the group of units of Zn = {k Mod(p)|(k, n) = 1}. What is
the order of this group?. Also what do you mean regarding the notation ? I know $\Bbb Z_p^*$ is the cyclic group of $z_p$ I though that was just what I wrote without the zero element though ?

Comment: @exodius Then see my answer:) You should **not** denote the group of units of $\Bbb{Z}_n$ again by $\Bbb{Z}_n$, but rather by, say, $U(n)$ or $\Bbb{Z}_n^*$.

Comment: @exodius: Note first that this is not what you wrote: he has $(k,n)$, you had $(n,p)$. Second, that is indeed a misprint, since $p$ is not defined anywhere; he presumably meant $\pmod{n}$. Third, he used poor phrasing which confused you: you thought it was “$\mathbb{Z}_n = \{k\bmod n\mid (k,n)=1\}$”, but what he really meant (badly phrased) was: $(\text{group of units of }\mathbb{Z}_n) = \{k\bmod n\mid (k,n)=1\}$. That is, it’s the description of “units of $\mathbb{Z}_n$”, not the description of $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ahhhh I see now. thank you for clearing that up for me :)

Answer (score 1):

1) "How do you find the group of units?" The group of units $U(n)$ of the *ring* $\Bbb{Z}_n$ has $\phi(n)$ elements, and just consists of the representatives $k$ with $0\le k\le n-1$ which are coprime to $n$. An arbitrary group does not have a group of units.

2) Indeed, the structure is different. First of all, $U(n)$ does not have oder $n$, but only $\phi(n)$, which is smaller than $n$ for $n\ge 2$. So the cyclic group $C_n$ of order $n$ and $U(n)$ have different orders, and moreover $U(n)$ need not be cyclic.

Comment: Thank you for answering number 1. number two however I meant something different. I meant what is the structure of the group $\Bbb Z_n=\{kmodp|(n,p)=1\}$, not the structure of the group of units

Comment: Oh wait is that the group of units ?

Comment: The notation confused me but is the $\Bbb Z_n$ I gave the group of units of $\Bbb Z_p$ ?

Comment: Yes, $U(n)$ is the group of units of $\Bbb{Z}_n$. You are confusing the notions, a bit (and also $n$ and $p$?).